# The language of all machines that accepts strings of even length

Tags: turing-machines, rice-theorem

I have difficulties in proving that for the given language:

$E V E N_{T M}=\{\langle M\rangle: M$ is a TM s.t. $|w|$ is even for all $w \in L(M)\}$.

prove that:
$E V E N_{T M} \in coRE$

I've tried to look at  $(E V E N_{T M})^\complement$  and prove that :

$(E V E N_{T M})^\complement \in RE$

by building TM M', that will simulate M on words ordered by MINLEX order from $\sum^*$:

```
 -if M accepts W ,M' check if w has odd length. if it has , M' accepts, otherwise M' continues 
   to the next word

  -if M rejects W, and w has odd length, M' accepts, otherwise rejects

  -if M doesn't stop, M' doesn't stop
```

Is it a right direction for solving this?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick required to construct the TM for $(EVEN_{TM})^C$ is that a TM can simulate finitely many TMs in each step, like so:

```
L = []
for word w with |w| odd:
    start simulation of M on w
    add the simulation to L
    for each simulation S in L:
        simulate S one more step
        if S halts and accepts: accept
        if S halts and rejects: 
            remove S from L
```

Here $\langle M \rangle$ is ofc the string whose membership we want to test.
If an odd length word exists and $w \in L(M)$ than this algorithm will encounter it at some point and start a simulation of $M$ on $w$ and since this simulation steps forward on every succinct iteration, at some point it will halt and our machine will terminate. If no such word exists, it will just loop forever.